# Cannot use Yolov8 model for object detection in ROS2

Tags: ros2, docker, object-detection

I'm trying to replace the ssd_mobilenet_v2 object detection model with my YOLOv8 model on an Autonomous Mobile Robot. I have already modified the paths and related files (xml, label, bin). But when running the object detection docker, the model path didn't change. The error as below:

```
InferenceEngine: 0x7faa723af030
Loading Inference Engine
Loading network files
Path to model: /home/eiforamr/workspace/object_detection/src/prebuilt_object_detection/object_detection/share/object_detection/models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco
Model file name: frozen_inference_graph.xml
Base file name: frozen_inference_graph
[ INFO ] Loading Inference Engine
[ INFO ] Device info: 
[ INFO ]    CPU
    MKLDNNPlugin version ......... 2021.4
    Build ........... 2
Loading network files
[ ERROR ] Unknown model format! Cannot find reader for model format: xml and read the model: /home/eiforamr/workspace/object_detection/src/prebuilt_object_detection/object_detection/share/object_detection/models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco/frozen_inference_graph.xml. Please check that reader library exists in your PATH.
[INFO] [1693665122.746289686] [i045.object_detection_node]: Start Tracking Bounding Boxes
[WARN] [1693665122.812514733] [i045.object_detection_node]: No data received in CameraTopic instance
```

I tried to search the "ssd_mobilenet_v2" in the folder and the result is:

```
$ grep -r -n ssd_mobilenet workspace
Binary file workspace/object_detection/src/prebuilt_object_detection/object_detection/bin/object_detection_node matches
Binary file workspace/object_detection/src/prebuilt_object_detection/object_detection/lib/object_detection/object_detection_node matches
```

I do can find it in the two files:

[image]

But the same error remained after I changed it. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
It is better to paste the text from the error rather than a screenshot. Images are not text-searchable. Thank you for your kind cooperation.